# Unterschied zwischen "Lehrgang" und "Praktikum"

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *Lehrgang* und *Praktikum*?

Comment: Damit wir die Frage wieder öffnen können, muss sie erst überarbeitet werden. Diese Meta-Frage kann dir vielleicht dabei helfen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das sind zwei völlig verschiedene Dinge. "Lehrgang" ist ein Kurs oder eine Ausbildung. Ein "Praktikum" kann zwar Bestandteil von einer Ausbildung sein, dabei wird jedoch speziell auf die Praxis (daher das Wort) geachtet. Es wird also Arbeit erwartet, um das Gelernte zu vertiefen und anzuwenden. Ein Praktikum wird in sehr vielen Fällen in einem Unternehmen stattfinden, der Lehrgang aber an einer Schule.